# Changing OBIEE server

Tags: obiee

I have a requirement where I want to change the OBIEE 11g server and point to the DR, keeping my presentation server as same.

Also how can I change the URL for analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a load balancer, and/or use DNS CNAME to change the IP that your URL resolves to.